# Can't track memory usage of MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, memory

I have a MySQL instance as a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container managed by [Hashicorp Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/) on an AWS EC2 [t4g](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t4/).small instance.
I need to monitor MySQL's memory usage because I have experienced OOM kills after approximately two days from launching the MySQL daemon and have to optimize the configuration.

`docker stats`, `atop`, and `htop` show that MySQL initially uses about 400MiB of RAM and the usage is slowly growing up.

[Memory usage graph by hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ocJ9.png)

The graph above shows an increase of about 150MiB of memory.
But [sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-memory-global-by-current-bytes.html) and [memory_global_total](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-memory-global-total.html) seem to say there is always constant memory usage. The queries show as the below regardless of time.

```sql
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(event_name,'/',2) AS
            code_area, FORMAT_BYTES(SUM(current_alloc))
            AS current_alloc
            FROM sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes
            GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(event_name,'/',2)
            ORDER BY SUM(current_alloc) DESC;
+---------------------------+---------------+
| code_area                 | current_alloc |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| memory/innodb             | 215.31 MiB    |
| memory/performance_schema | 159.17 MiB    |
| memory/sql                | 17.18 MiB     |
| memory/mysys              | 9.01 MiB      |
| memory/temptable          | 1.00 MiB      |
| memory/mysqld_openssl     | 160.50 KiB    |
| memory/mysqlx             | 2.89 KiB      |
| memory/myisam             |  696 bytes    |
| memory/csv                |   88 bytes    |
| memory/blackhole          |   88 bytes    |
| memory/vio                |   16 bytes    |
+---------------------------+---------------+

mysql> select * from sys.memory_global_total;
+-----------------+
| total_allocated |
+-----------------+
| 425.03 MiB      |
+-----------------+
```

I tweaked MySQL configurations several times, the latest version is:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
datadir=/srv/mysql
max_connections=20
temptable_max_ram=128M
temptable_max_mmap=128M

# You can see the live-updated configuration on remote: https://github.com/femiwiki/nomad/blob/main/mysql/my.cnf
```

But it is too hard to configure invisible memory usage. How I monitor the memory usage and what is the best way to prevent OOM kill?

Best regards.

#### Versions

- OS - Amazon Linux 2 LTS Arm64 AMI 2.0.20210427.0 arm64 Minimal HVM ebs
- MySQL - 8.0.24 for Linux on aarch64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
- Docker - 20.10.4, build d3cb89e
- Nomad - 1.0.4

Comment: Hello! Have you been able to fix the issue, we are encountering the same problem in production.

Comment: 1. I temporarily set up Percona Monitoring and Management which showed me graphs rather than numbers. 2. I have randomly tweaked the configurations:  https://github.com/femiwiki/nomad/compare/a65db922..7bed4bea#diff-f3c7fa01bdf84e83d97add3c841c7c8279fdb3f8912f49d5f280a4ffbdb5cf9d Now the OOM does not occur, but I don't know the exact cause.

Comment: This issue is quite confusing, we've started experimenting with your config file. Thank you for you time.